# DSolve is returning the same equation

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions

The equation I am trying to solve on Mathematica is programmed as follows:

```
ode1 = {y''[x] + (2 E - ((2 w^2/a^2) (1 - Cos[ax])) - ((g/(2*a^3)) (Sin[3*a*x] - Sin[a*x])))*y[x] == 0}

DSolve[ode1,y[x],x]
```

returns the DSolve as it is with ode1 in the argument. Am I doing something wrong? Please guide.

Comment: Usually returning DSolve means that there is no solution that it can find. You do have one `ax` which I am guessing should be `a*x` but making that change does not provide a solution.

Comment: `ParametricNDSolve` works here.

Comment: ```ParametricNDSolve``` is a numeric solver, not a symbolic solver.

Comment: @AQ: Did you look in a handbook of E. Kamke for it?

Comment: Maple 2021 fails with it, even for concrete values of parameters.